# Why would SAS proc mixed produce residual variance estimates under AR1 covariance structure, but none for unstructured covariance?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, residuals, covariance-matrix, sas

I am working on a program in SAS that seeks to extract r2 based on the residual variance produced by covariance parameter estimates in `PROC MIXED`.

The specification of the covariance structure was previously specified as *unstructured*, because AIC comparisons and case studies determined it was the best fit.
The problem is that a residual variance estimate is **not produced** when I specify the covariance structure as `type=un` (unstructured). A snippet of the code is below.

```
 proc mixed data=unidata method=ml;
  class SUBNUM drugcode time;
  model y= baselinescore  DRUGCODEN time  time*drugcode/solution cl;
  repeated time /subject=SUBNUM type=un r rcorr;
```

When we initially looked at covariance structures for this data, it came down to *unstructured* and *autoregressive* covariance structures; they had the lowest AICs and best described the within-subject correlation in the repeated measurements design. AR(1) actually scored slightly better on AIC. I suspect that TYPE=UN was specified for this data mainly due to convention and the fact that the difference between AR(1) and UN covariance structures had minimal effect on the model results.

But now that we need to extract r2 from the model, it's hard to determine why the unstructured covariance provides **no residual variance estimates**, while AR(1) structure does provide an estimate. Is something wrong with my code that is resulting in no residuals under Covariance Parameter Estimates, or is it *because* of the covariance structure I specified?

Many thanks for reading and any guidance.

Comment: With AR(1), there is a single variance parameter that multiplies the autocorrelation matrix to give you the covariance matrix. Notice that the diagonals are all equal to this number. With an unstructured covariance matrix, the diagonal elements are all different numbers, ie, there are different variances. Thus there is not one single number that you can identify to be *the* residual variance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps. How might you go about assessing the best fit in this case, given that the AICs are similar (AR (1) is slightly lower), the results are not significantly affected, but residual variance is needed to calculate an f2? Since the unstructured covariance matrix can't provide a the residual variance, it seems I may need to re-do all the analyses with AR(1) instead. Can you comment on any other implications? Many thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The AR(1) covariance matrix is:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 & \rho^2\sigma^2 & \rho^3\sigma^2 \\
    \rho\sigma^2 & \sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 & \rho^2\sigma^2 \\
    \rho^2\sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 & \sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 \\
    \rho^3\sigma^2 & \rho^2\sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 & \sigma^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or just
$$
\sigma^2 \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \rho & \rho^2 & \rho^3 \\
    \rho & 1 & \rho & \rho^2 \\
    \rho^2 & \rho & 1 & \rho \\
    \rho^3 & \rho^2 & \rho & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The diagonal elements are all $\sigma^2$, indicating constant variance at each time point. The off-diagonal elements represent covariances, which decrease as the time interval between measurements increases. The pattern is symmetric, reflecting the assumption that the correlation structure is the same forward and backward in time.

Note that, to estimate this, we have to estimate just two parameters, $\rho$ (the covariaance) and $\sigma^2$, the "residual variance"

Whereas the unstructured matrix is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{1}^2 & \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{13} & \sigma_{14} \\
    \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{2}^2 & \sigma_{23} & \sigma_{24} \\
    \sigma_{13} & \sigma_{23} & \sigma_{3}^2 & \sigma_{34} \\
    \sigma_{14} & \sigma_{24} & \sigma_{34} & \sigma_{4}^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for which each entry is a separate covariance estimate, and consequently there is no single "residual variance".

It is often the case that AIC (and especially BIC) favour the AR(1) model due to the number of parameters that have to be estimated in the unstructured model.